# SQL Procedure Syntax

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm attempting to create a stored procedure in MySQL but it's throwing me a syntax error

Here is my Code:

Create Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE video_series_filter (_categoryID bigint, _mentorID bigint, _difficulty smallint, _searchTerm varchar(750), _start int, _record int)
```

The Line throwing error

```
IF _searchTerm IS NOT NULL
    SET _where = CONCAT("WHERE (s.title LIKE '%"_searchTerm"%' OR s.description LIKE '%"_searchTerm"%') ");
END IF;
```

Not sure why it's displaying a syntax error.  Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL's syntax for `IF` statements includes a mandatory `THEN` keyword.

Also the CONCAT() function needs commas between its arguments.

```
IF _searchTerm IS NOT NULL THEN
    SET _where = CONCAT("WHERE (s.title LIKE '%", _searchTerm, "%' OR s.description LIKE '%", _searchTerm, "%') ");
END IF;
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if.html for details.

Comment: However, now im getting an error when I CALL the procedure: #1064 - ""... syntax error near 'Series AS s JOIN Categories AS c ON s.category_id = c.id JOIN Mentors AS m ON s.' at line 1

Comment: I think this may be because I'm passing a null value, how can I create my procedure in such a way that it can pas null values for certain arguments?

Comment: Sounds like you are creating a dynamic SQL statement. Look into the [COALESCE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to turn null values into something non-null.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to CONCAT (or any function) must be separated by commas:

```
CONCAT("WHERE (s.title LIKE '%", _searchTerm, "%' OR s.description LIKE '%", _searchTerm, "%') ");
```